# How to get absolute position of clicked tr?

Tags: html, jquery, material-components

I'm using the menu from Material. I want to make a dropdown menu when the user is right-clicking on tr, but the menu pops at the table header position. (X coordinate works properly, but Y coordinates are stuck at table header's position)

```
$(document).on('contextmenu','#table2 tr',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   let parentOffset = $(this).offset();
   menu.open = false;
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
   menu.setAbsolutePosition(e.pageX - parentOffset.left, e.pageY - parentOffset.top);
   menu.open = true;
});
```

How to fix coordinates?

Comment: `setAbsolutePosition` is MDC function to set menu's coords from left bottom corner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('contextmenu','#table2 tr',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   menu.open = false;
   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
   menu.setAbsolutePosition(e.clientX, e.clientY);
   menu.open = true;
});
```

Problem solved because `setAbsolutePosition` sets position from parent's position (I didn't know that). I just put menu elements right after body tag and used `menu.setAbsolutePosition(e.clientX, e.clientY);`, now everything works properly